# Changing default behaviour of the Contacts app in Oreo

Tags: contacts, 8.0-oreo, motorola-moto-z2-play

When you open up the Contacts app second or the following time, it always shows last view (i.e. where I left it), i.e. the most recent contact search.

I am using this app purely for searching the contacts, so the need of tapping *Back* to go back to recent search results list and then tapping *X* to clear the last query **each time** I want to search for another contact simply kills me. This is as stupid UX approach as it can be.

Is there any way to change the default view, in which Contacts app opens by default each time?

My stack:

- Motorola Moto Z2 Play,
- Android 8.0 Oreo.

I am using the default, system Contacts app. No 3rd party solution.

Comment: On my Sony XA2 (Android 8) the contact app works exactly the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

it occurs because you didn't clear it from the recent apps, next time clear the contacts app and relaunch it.